# Excel vba: program takes a long time if status bar is renewed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program that creates `100 000` objects of class `Client`, puts them into array and then goes through that array `100` times, each time assigning each `Client` a different random number through `Rnd()` function:

Main sub:

```
Sub start()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim clientsColl() As Client
    ReDim clientsColl(1 To 100000) As Client

    For j = 1 To 100000
        Set clientsColl(j) = New Client
        clientsColl(j).setClientName = "Client_" & j

        Application.StatusBar = "Getting client " & j

        DoEvents
    Next


    Dim tempCount As Long
    Dim clientCopy As Variant
    For i = 1 To 100
        tempCount = 0
        For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
            tempCount = tempCount + 1

            clientCopy.generateRandom

            'Application.StatusBar = "Calculating " & i & ": " & tempCount & "/" & 100000  '(1)

            'DoEvents
        Next

        Application.StatusBar = "Calculating " & i

        DoEvents
    Next

    MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

`Client` class:

```
Option Explicit

Dim clientName As String
Dim randomNumber As Double

Public Sub generateRandom()
    randomNumber = Rnd()
End Sub

Public Property Get getClientName()
    getClientName = clientName
End Property

Public Property Let setClientName(value As String)
    clientName = value
End Property
```

The problem is, the execution time depends on whether or not line `(1)` is commented out. If it's executed, the statusbar gets renewed, but the execution time is very slow. If it's not executed, the program gets done really fast.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you familiar with `Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.StatusBar` `Application` properties?

Comment: @AntiDrondert I tried adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the `start` macros, its seems to be working faster, but the fundamental problem: that if the inner statusbar is renewed the macros is slower still exists.

Comment: "the fundamental problem: that if the inner statusbar is renewed the macros is slower still exists": So you think the time which is needed updating the status bar could be 0? It surely cannot be 0.

Comment: @Ans Compare status bar flickering to screen flickering, when `Application.ScreenUpdating` is `True`. Statement itself is false, ofcourse, but it gives the general idea of what is happening. It spends time (I don't know numbers) to access `Application.StatusBar` properties and update them on each iteration (total of 100). It is similiar to updating Worksheet data, when screen updating is turned off. I should add that `Client` class module is irrelevant in this question.

Comment: Status bar is ultimately visual indicator so it will take some time. How long does your program take with and without it?

Comment: When the status bar is updated, it is not slow because it works 100 * 100000 times.

Comment: @AntiDrondert Thank you for the answer. But isn't the statusbar supposed to be renewed in a separate thread, so that it wouldn't affect the other thread's computations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is fast enough as long as you stay within. Whenever you turn to Excel, it may get much slower because Excel makes thousands of operations every time it gets control. You may consider turning off a few more services of Excel like I do in my applications:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

... and as far as I know DoEvents is the best way to make Excel update the status bar when you turn off automatic updates. 
Another timesaving workaround can be to display only every 100th or 1000th message from within the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

when doing a progressbar or statusbar, you need to use it wisely.

Basically the progress info needs to be refreshed only every 0.1 seconds or so.

Knowing your max number of loops , and the time it takes, you might want to update the info only every (in your case) , let's say, 100 iterations of the loop.

This is done like this:  if j mod 100=0 then application.statusbar="..." : doevents

Usually i even go further by using doevents less than my progressbar (second if j mod).

Comment: But wouldn't that check `j MOD 100 = 0` that would need to happen at every iteration slow down execution time as well?

Comment: the doevents would slow down way more then a simple if